# The grammar analysis of "if I'd known what that wand was going out into the world to do, ..."

Tags: grammar

Especially, I want the grammar analysis if the part after "if I'd known" which is:

> what that wand was going out into the world to do

What is the function of "what"?

What is the function of "that wand"?

What is the function of the other words in the following? Is "out" a part of the verb "was going"?

Comment: ***What*** refers to whatever that wand was going out into the world to do (which I don't know, but presumably at time of speaking the speaker *had* belatedly discovered this).

Comment: That wand presumably refers to a wand in a Harry Potter book. If it doesn't, context would help. Only in Harry Potter are wands personified, afaik. to go out into the world is an expression. Personification is a literary device. Here, the wand is like a person.

Comment: You asked about the grammar. "What that wand was going out into the world to do” is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question). The pronoun “what” is functioning as object of the verb “do”. The noun phrase “that wand” (determiner +noun) functions as subject of the subordinate clause, and “out” functions as head the PP “out into the word”. The meaning is "If I’d known the answer to the question ‘What was that wand going out into the world to do?"’